# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier в import

Tags: node.js

При компиляции проекта появляется ошибка.
[image: Ошибка]

Код компилируемого файла:

```
'use strict'
import def from "./src/classes/server";

def.start();
```

Код подключаемого файла:

```
'use strict'

import express from "express";

export default class Server
{
    static start(port)
    {
        const app = express();

        app.get('/', (req, res) => {
            res.sendfile(__dirname + "/src/index.html");
        });

        app.listen(port);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ксли я правильно помню, модули экспериментальны и всё ещё за флагом

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Comment: что ты называешь _компиляцией_ проекта, как ты ее запускаешь? что для этого используется?